# Using std.algorithm.iteration.sum with Duration[]

Tags: d, phobos

Why I can't use [`std.algorithm.iteration.sum`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#sum) with `Duration[]` ?

I thought I can use the `sum` in the same way than e.g. with `int[]`:

```
int[] ints = [40, 27, 5];
int intSum = ints.sum();
assert(intSum == 72);
```

But instead I get an unexpected (unexpected for me at least) compilation error:

```
/usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/algorithm/iteration.d(5885): Error: struct `core.time.Duration` member this is not accessible
so_002.d(11): Error: template instance `std.algorithm.iteration.sum!(Duration[])` error instantiating
```

I kind of understand the compilation error but I fail to understand why the limitation exists as for me there is nothing in documentation explaining this.

I have read:

- [`sum`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#sum)
- [`Duration`](https://dlang.org/phobos/core_time.html#.Duration)

Doesn't `Duration[]` conform with the constraints of `sum`:

```
auto sum(R)(R r)
if (isInputRange!R && !isInfinite!R && is(typeof(r.front + r.front)));
```

Or have I overlooked something else ?

The workaround is easy - use [`fold`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#fold) instead.

```
import std.algorithm : fold, sum;
import std.datetime : Duration, minutes;

void main()
{
  Duration[] durations = [40.minutes, 27.minutes, 5.minutes];

  // Unexpected compilation error:
  // /usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/algorithm/iteration.d(5885): Error: struct `core.time.Duration` member this is not accessible
  // so_002.d(11): Error: template instance `std.algorithm.iteration.sum!(Duration[])` error instantiating

  // auto durationSum = durations.sum();

  // fold works as expected
  Duration durationSum = durations.fold!((a, b) => a + b);
  assert(durationSum == 72.minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `sum` with zero arguments (except for the UFCS arg) tries to create a seed element of value zero, by calling the constructor `Duration(0)`. While `Duration(0)` sorta makes sense, what is the value of `Duration(1)` - one minute? One second? One aeon? For this reason, `Duration(0)` simply doesn't compile. The reason why `fold` works is it always takes the first element as its seed. The drawback is it throws when the range it operates on is empty.

Now, you may not care too much about that, and just want `durations.sum()` to work. Fret not - there's a way. You will have to pass the seed value to `sum()` as `durations.sum(Duration.zero)`.

Filed as a bug: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19525